Safely grounding RV site which has no ground conductor to house main panel?
Gordian Knot here-
200A Square-D meterbase has ground rod with #4 bare copper + 2/0-2/0-1 URD -> 1974 mobile home 200A Square-D Homeline main panel.
2/2/4 URD ON 100A 2 pole breaker in this box runs to RV spot ~ 75' distant but there is no ground conductor.  This RV box is a 100A Square-D Homeline with meter socket. 5 of 10 spaces used-a single pole 30A (RV), 20A 120V water heater, 15A for heat tape, 15A exterior lite circuit and 30A 240V welder outlet (just in case).
Running a new grounding conductor from main panel to RV panel just not feasible due to very rocky ground/huge stone retaining wall/tree roots/septic system/fact that I'm an old guy...ditto no way to run it directly to original mobile meterbase ground rod-unless it was to be buried no more than 6" deep.  I do have a spool of #6 URD I've been tripping over for years and have toyed with the idea of digging a trench with the pressure washer and shoving that in on the theory that something is better than nothing.
The more I read about grounding the less I understand...1 rod/2 rods/no rods/bond a new ground rod to the neutral in the RV box/don't bond it...  BTW, there is no isolated ground terminal strip in the RV box so currently all neutrals and grounds connected to neutral terminal strip. Everything is TIGHT, noco paste on all alu connections, no splices in box or any circuits.
What are my options?  Rural area in MT, no inspections but I want to be safe even if I'm not code-compliant.

Neutral and ground can(should) only be bonded together at the main panel.  Ground rods at a site away from the main building are more for lighting/power surges/unequal ground voltage.Older sub panels were connected like yours are, but code changed.  Code usually only changes to protect people/keep them from dying, but do not know the reason.

Ground rods are a very weak substitute for a ground wire.
Since you're not even using 240V anyway, just go ahead and rearrange it so it is hot/neutral/ground 2/2/4.
That was easy!
You don't want to be running this groundless ("combined neutral and ground" which is nonsense).  British houses are wired that way, and John Ward has an interesting discussion about it here (note the part where RCD=GFCI doesn't help at all).  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRHyqouJPzE Note that the British don't allow RV sites or boat ramps to be wired that way.

Abandoning the welder socket for a single 120V leg is the cheap way out
Harper's proposal of converting it to a 120V feeder is the cheapest and easiest way out of this, but it does mean you have to abandon the welder outlet at the RV site, unless you can run your welder or whatever plugs into that socket on 120V as well.
If you need 240V, a transformer is your best bet
If you absolutely need 240V at the RV site for some reason, your best bet to clean this up is by using a NEMA 3R dry-type transformer to essentially "regenerate" neutral at the RV site.  You'll need to use a 25kVA, 240/480 to 120/240 transformer for this, with the primary wired for 240V operation, the incoming neutral repurposed as your grounding wire, and the secondary set up for 120/240V center-tapped use with the outgoing neutral connected to the center tap, grounding rods fitted at the RV site if they are not already present, and a bonding jumper run from the transformer enclosure to the existing RV-site panel.
This does have the advantage that the existing RV box can remain with little or no modification, which may not be true if you ran a grounding wire from the house to the RV site.  (It depends on if the RV box has an isolated neutral or not; if it cannot be converted for service entrance use otherwise, adding an 8AWG copper bonding jumper between the neutral and the grounding bars is certainly workable.)
